# Geb functional tests in Grails fail because the web application has not been started

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying out the Geb (0.5.1) Grails (1.3.5) integration. When using the JUnit runner (extends grails.plugin.geb.GebTests) the web application is not started before the Geb test is executed. Therefore the test fails, with Firefox saying it can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8090.

In the same test-app run the functional selenium tests (selenium-rc 1.0.2 plugin) run without a problem.

Anybody an idea on why the grails web application is not started before the Geb functional tests, while it is correctly started for the Selenium functional tests?

```
import geb.*

class GebTests extends grails.plugin.geb.GebTests {

    void testIndexSearch() {
        Browser.drive("http://localhost:8090/agora") {
            go('/admin')
            assert title == 'the title'
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ruben, is this test in the test/functional directory in your Grails project?

Comment: Yes, the test is in the test/functional/xx/yy/zz directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser.drive() shouldn't be needed. Have you tried the following?

```
import geb.*

class GebTests extends grails.plugin.geb.GebTests {
    void testIndexSearch() {
        go('/admin')
        assert title == 'the title'
    }
}
```

To set a base URL other than the root of the Grails app, add:

```
String getBaseUrl() { "http://some/url" }
```

Comment: After removing the surrounding Browser.drive(){} statement the test succeeds. Thx